# Как установить ссылки от решения к библиотеки классов через команду вид -> терминал?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019

Решение имеет три проекта: консольное приложение, библиотеку классов, тестовый проект.
Необходимо установить ссылки от решения к библиотеки классов.
С помощью какой команды это сделать?

Comment: Если библиотека уже в решении, то ничего делать не нужно. Подключаете неймспейс и вперед.

Comment: в задание указано установить ссылку через терминал

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-add-reference